# Why SAXParser doesn't like namespace in root element?

Tags: java, xml, sax

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
  <ui:define name="title">
    <h:outputText value="some text"/>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

This is what [SAXParser](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html) from [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/) is saying:

```
Cannot find the declaration of element 'ui:composition'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: WHat version of xerces?  This should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have *XML Schema validation* turned on, and the parser doesn't know where to find the XSD for the namespace?

What does the code look to parse the XML?

Answer (score 1):

did you configure the saxparser to be namespace aware?  (that is usually disabled by default).  (you configured this on the SAXParserFactory before creating the SAXParser).

Answer (score 0):

I predict that the real error message looks like:

SAXParseException:cvc - elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element ...

and that would indicate that you turned on schema validation without enough schema.